# Function pointers that call one function

Tags: pointer, core-libraries, functions, stm32

I'm reading a library file `timer.h` for STM core library that I just installed in Arduino hardware folder.

Of course, there has to be a lot of questions for me as a beginner about many approaches/stratgegies that programmers rule in writing the code.

One thing is that calling a function with a function pointer that only call one function, but the difference is that the function pointer is declared/defined as an inline function.

---

Edit: I deleted the code and posted a link for it in github.

[stm32/timer header file](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32/blob/master/STM32F1/system/libmaple/include/libmaple/timer.h#L595)

OK, the part that I started to think about starts from line 595.

It's functions declarations.

In line 598, it's a declaration for a function that receiver a pointer to a function.

In later lines, starting from line 634, these functions have only one line to execute. So my question is why to develop a function to only execute one line ?

Why they didn't just put that line directly instead of putting it inside function ?

Comment: Could you please post a link to the complete file?

Comment: Where exactly is the function pointer here, that is called? `bb_perip` is not a function pointer, I think, but a function, that returns a pointer to a variable. Though I cannot be sure from this snippet of code alone

Comment: `...\Program_Files\Arduino\hardware\Arduino_STM32-master\STM32F1\system\libmaple\include\libmaple` for example depending on the root file location on my computer.

Comment: I posted like most the inline functions. Couldn't post the complete code that is far more that the character limitations over 30000 character.

Comment: Again I don't see a function pointer being used here. Please point us, where exactly you are seeing the problem. Also can you please give a link to your used STM32 core, so that we can read this file on the web. I personally don't have a STM32-core installed, also we don't know, which core you used. Best case would be a github link to the file in question.

Comment: OK, I added the information in the main post. It's much easier for me, but I don't know which is better to add the required information here or edit the main post ?

Comment: @R1S8K - Please edit the question and add new information to it.

Answer (score 2):

`bb_perip` is a function that returns a pointer to a bit from a register that is related to a specific timer peripheral (there's more than one).  That pointer is then dereferenced with the `*` operator to make `*bb_perip(...)`.

What `bb_perip` returns is dependent on what timer you are using and what value you are interested in.

`bb_perip` is not a pointer to a function, it is a normal function that happens to return a pointer.

Comment: Something new to me is that there is an integer passed to this function ! It's my first time to encounter this feature. `*bb_perip(&(dev->regs).bas->CR1, TIMER_CR1_CEN_BIT) = 0;` there is a 0 passed to this function, how this is done ?

Comment: No, the integer is not being passed to the function. The integer is being assigned to the dereferenced pointer returned from the function.

Comment: oooh I'm sorry my mistake I wanted to say "assigned" not "passed" :) totally different approaches. Yeah, I meant it's a new feature to me to assign anything to a function.

Comment: Or because it's a function pointer, where the pointer is a variable basically, so I can assign a value for it. is that correct ?

Comment: You are *not* assigning *anything* to the function.  The function returns a pointer to somewhere in memory. You take that pointer, then use it to place a value into memory at that address.  Once the function has returned the pointer *it has no further role to play*.  You can just as well use (in pseudocode) `*func() = 4` as you can `pointer = func(); *pointer = 4;` - all you're doing is leaving out the middleman.

Comment: Oh yeah I understand now they put 0 because the function role is to pause the timer. `static inline void timer_pause(timer_dev *dev) {
    *bb_perip(&(dev->regs).bas->CR1, TIMER_CR1_CEN_BIT) = 0;
}
`